# Attempted to load class from namespace Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine 2. 
I created an entity Product and when I want to add a product in the database it return me an error:

Attempted to load class "Produit" from namespace "Dwm\catalogueBundle\Entity" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RESTApi/src/Dwm/catalogueBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 41. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

```
<?php

namespace Dwm\catalogueBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Dwm\catalogueBundle\Entity\Produit;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
* @Route("/addProduit/{nom}/{prix}")
* @Template()
*/
public function addProduitAction($nom, $prix)
{

$p = new Produit();
$p->setNom($nom);
$p->setPrix($prix);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($p);
$em->flush();

return array('ptoduit'=>$p);
}
}
```

Comment: `Produit` or `Product`?

Comment: You are useing `Produit` instead of `Product`, in 5 cases.
`use Dwm\catalogueBundle\Entity\Produit;`
`* @Route("/addProduit/{nom}/{prix}")`
`public function addProduitAction($nom, $prix)`
`$p = new Produit();`
`return array('ptoduit'=>$p);`
And I think your file is named wrong too. Just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think this is the root cause, but your bundle name should be in camel case: CatalogueBundle rather than catalogueBundle. It might not be causing this, but will definitely mess up other things as you go on.

Comment: It could very well be the problem with case-sensitive file systems.